# Hyphenated Relationships in Salesforce

Tags: lookup, relationships, master-detail

I would like to understand the term "hyphenated relationships" in Salesforce.
Are these below "hyphenated relationships" in Salesforce?

- Master-Detail Relationship
- Lookup Relationship
- Parent-Child Relationship

And also please help me to understand that for hyphenated relationships like Parent-Child and Master-Detail, we always refer to the "other" object first, then to the object in question. Please correct me if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I think you are asking how to reference children or parents from some target object.  Is that correct?

Comment: Where did you find the term "hyphenated relationships"? Never heard it before

Comment: Yes, you are correct @cropredy. But what is this "hyphenated relationship"?

Comment: Hi @SebastianKessel, see the response here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150205/question-on-salesforce-relationship. It is mentioned there. So I would like to understand the concept

Comment: You seem to have fallen victim to a language barrier, The term that sfdcfox used, "hyphenated relationships" really means relationships where two terms are separated by a hyphen. "Master-Detail" and "Parent-Child" fit this bill. "Lookup", obviously, doesnt.

Comment: Ok. So for "hyphenated relationships" i.e. Master-Detail", "Parent-Child", we will always say the child object first followed by parent object?

Comment: Actually, quite the opposite.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a code question, it is a terminology one

Comment: Exactly that is the place where I also got confused. In Master-Detail, Parent-Child, One-To-Many we should state the parent object first followed by the child object

Comment: @SebastianKessel There are many questions asked here about Salesforce that don't involve code. If code were the primary criteria for closing a question, then you could probably go back and close at least 25% of the questions in the database.

Comment: @crmprogdev i feel this is neither a code nor, really, a SFDC question. the OP has a question about understanding how some terminology (really, a term coined by sfdfox, imho) applies in general. However, i won't take it personally at all if you (or most) vote to keep it open.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I was just trying to make it clear that not having code in a question wasn't in my view a valid reason to close a question. I understand you point. That said, we also see a fair share of questions about Salesforce relationships and terminology as well. We have a voting system for a reason and we'll see how the votes go. :)

Comment: In that, we agree. I definitely apply the above criteria in a case-by-case basis. I felt that, in this case, it was warranted. And the votes system is exactly why I didn't really hesitate to nominate it....  :)

Comment: Hi SebastianKessel and crmprogdev, The intention of this question was to clear the concept. Even though there in no coding involved, but I personally feel understanding relationship concept(how salesforce relationship works) is a very important stuff. That is the reason why I put this question here. Hope I calrified my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [sfdcfox's answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/150206/24889), mentioned in the comments on the question, 'hyphenated relationship' simply means a relationship type whose descriptive name contains a hyphen '-' (also called a dash, an em dash, or an en dash, depending on how wide the dash is).

'Master-Detail' (the hyphen is between 'Master' and 'Detail') and 'Parent-Child' (the hyphen is between 'Parent' and 'Child') are two examples.

It is not a separate relationship type, and the term is not used anywhere in official documentation.

Comment: One-To-Many is also "hyphenated relationship" then?

Comment: One-to-Many is a _property_ of a relationship in Salesforce, but is not strictly a relationship type in Salesforce. Generally speaking, any one relationship field has this one-to-many property. This particular term is uncommon on the Salesforce platform (it's more commonly used by database designers/administrators)

Comment: For example, say you have `Opportunity` and `OpportunityLineItem` (`OLI` for short). The relationship between `Opportunity` and `OLI` is a Master-Detail relationship (`Opportunity` being the 'Master' part or 'Master' side of the relationship, and `OLI` being the 'Detail' part or 'Detail' side) of the relationship. The relationship field itself resides on `OLI`, making it possible to relate many `OLIs` to a single `Opportunity`. `OLI` therefore has a many-to-one relationship to `Opportunity`. Conversely, `Opportunity` has a one-to-many relationship to `OLI`.

Comment: Clear to me. Thanks for the clarification. I was confused with the question mentioned in the post http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/150205/question-on-salesforce-relationship. My answer to this multiple choice question was: Lookup relationship. But it was mentioned One-To-Many as the correct answer.

Comment: Both Lookup and Master-Detail are One-To-Many relationships. However, I agree with you that, in this case, Lookup is the correct answer.

Comment: @SebastianKessel On the related question, the mock exam asks for the relationship between `Account` and `Warehouse` (not the other way around). `Warehouse` has a lookup relationship to `Account`, but `Account` doesn't have a lookup relationship to `Warehouse`. 'One to Many' describes the property of the relationship between `Account` and `Warehouse` even though there is no relationship field on `Account` to `Warehouse`. I think the quality of this particular mock question is questionable.

Comment: I've taken several SFDC certification exams and never seen a question like this, ergo, I do not believe that sfdcfox's answer is correct. Those questions normally ask for a specific SFDC solution, not a DB concept. If this is an SFDC mock exam, however, I will be wrong but very surprised. My money says this was something somebody else wrote.